# Is Base64 a common format between the widely used formats?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image

To be honest, I don't really know much about image formatting, or what base64 actually is, but let's say I convert a .jpg to base64 like this:

```
  my_base_64 = Base64.strict_encode64('kittens.jpg')
```

I can then display this base64 string as a .png like this:

```
<img src="data:image/png;base64,<%= my_base_64 %>" />
```

I can right click and save the image, the .jpg does appear to be a fully fledged .png, though without transparency.

Is this the point of base64? A common format that enables any image to become any other image?

If you look at how I'm doing the above, will this work for all image types? Not only a .jpg but .tiff jpeg2000 ect... could I have a list of what formats won't work? .psd probably won't work at all, for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

base64 only uses the characters a-z A-Z 0-9 + /

Using base64, you can encode any binary file using only the above printable characters. This allows you to include binary content within a context that normally does not accept binary data. For example, an email could include an image as base64, so that you do not have to load the image via a web request (img src=url). Many email clients will not load the image, as doing so could indicate to a spammer that the email recipient exists through some tracking tag in the image's URL. So by including the image as base64, it is delivered with the email itself.

Another example of base64 is get-pip.py, which is a python script that includes within itself a complete copy of the ZIP archive as a base64 string. This allows it to resolve the dependency of needing itself to install itself: It just uses that archive to import the pip code, so that it can install pip on the local system.

base64 is not a magical image transcoder. Likely, the browser is reading the base64 string, converting it into a binary format, and determining that it is a JPG from some magical byte code in the resulting image. Use base64 when you need to send binary data in a text-like form.